# Postman request receiving cookies but Postman not detecting them

Tags: laravel, cookies, postman

I've recently started using Postman and I am testing an API where I get a CSRF token and then login but I always get a CSRF token mismatch. I am including X-XSRF-TOKEN header but I think the issue is around the cookies not being stored correctly.

I am calling a Laravel Sanctum endpoint to get a CSRF token and when I look in the in the console I can see Set-Cookie response headers

[image: Postman console showing cookies being set]

However, when I look in the cookies tab it says no cookies were received from the server

[image: Cookies response tab in postman]

However, when I look at the cookies store they are listed for my test domain (home.local)

[image: Postman cookie store]

Due to this issue, when I send a request to the login, the session cookies are not sent in the request as shown in the console on the request to the login endpoint

[image: Login request from postman console showing no cookies]

I can do this fine using Insomnia.Rest client so I know the API is working as expected - I am however trying to replace Insomnia with Postman.

I've tried Google, but I've only found some bugs that were introduced that seemed to cause something similar back in 2016

### Update

I managed to Postman working with production fine using a pre-request script to get the CSRF token and set the environment variable using the below:

```
const url = pm.environment.get('base_url');
const referer = pm.environment.get('Referer');
pm.sendRequest({
    url: `${url}/sanctum/csrf-cookie`,
    method: 'GET',
}, function (err, response, {cookies}) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("cookies", cookies);
        pm.environment.set('xsrf_token', cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'))
    }
});
```

Although this worked on production and successfully did the POST request, on my local dev PC, I was still getting the CSRF mismatch.

Although the request/response looked the same between dev/and prod I for some reason had the idea to change my dev URL from `my-app.home.local` to `my-app.home.com` and now the cookies are received and send in the next request to login without getting a CSRF token mismatch.

There's clearly an issue with postman here but not sure if it's something I'm doing or a bug in Postman. Does .local mean something different?

Comment: I'm not submitting this as an answer (because looking at your cookie, this isn't the problem), but for others who might be stumbling upon this issue, this might be helpful. For me, it turned out that Postman was fastidiously respecting the "Secure" flag on the cookie. Our production application handles TLS at the load balancer, and forwards unencrypted http traffic to web servers. And, for local development, TLS is all turned off. However, the login cookie still had the "Secure" flag turned on. Postman was (appropriately) not storing the cookie that came from a non-https website (localhost).